# Not turning over, and no movement on the stator shaft

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, starter

My bike - suzuki 81 450 L - recently overheated and died. My fallure, 90-plus degree day and I forgot to check the oil before I left.

I'm getting a click when starting and no attempt to turn over.

I played with it kicking it with some kind of electrical issue, which has been the big thing in the past. Battery look good, the voltage drop when cranking didn't seem too extreme.

I popped the cover off the signal generator, and noticed that the shaft was not spinning freely, just barely when I would get a click.  I worked on this before, when I first got the bike and I knew it wasn't right. I spent a little time working it loose with a wrench and afterwards she would start up and run just fine for a minute or two.

Where do I look next?

Comment: You sure the engine isn't seized?

Comment: It'll start and run for a few minutes.. didn't think that would be possible? @paulster2

Comment: If it'll run, it's not seized. I didnt pick that up in your question.